# Gradient Of Bezier Curve At Given Point

Tags: algorithm, math, physics, bezier

I cant seem to figure out how to calculate the incline of a curve for the following situation...

Essentially what I am trying to do is increase the speed of an object based on the incline of the curve at a particular point. The speed will be reduced if the incline is upwards and increase if downward.

I was using the derivative of a point t on the bezier curve to establish the tangent but this doesnt seem to be right as I would expect that value to be negative if the slope is downward.

I have been using the below equation for the tangent to evaluate X, Y and Z but then I only use Y to establish the incline...I think that step may be wrong

[image]

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Ultimately this is an object moving along an inclined plane but I cant establish the angle of the plane in order to do this, I believe if I could correctly find the angle it may solve the problem. I tried to take the point in question and then another point in front (so for example t = 0.5 and then a point in front would be t=0.51) and then calculate the angle using tan. I completely ignore the Z axis but is that wrong? If not how should I calculate the angle?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Would be a better fit for [math.stackexchange.com](http://www.math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146944/getting-the-derivative-of-a-bezier-curve-problem-in-cocos2d

Comment: It is not on maths. It is on how to put the known formulae as algorythm so that the result will be as expected.

Comment: Gradient and B'(t) are different things, right? This should be on math. @Gangnus, the formula is wrong, I think... B'(t) = dB/dt and gradient is (dB/dx,dB/dy,dB/dz).

Comment: @Ishtar try to think of it as a segment in 3D and its projection. Yes, gradient is what you are writing here. But it is not about 3d curves, it is about 3d scalar fields. You can't find angles of slopes with it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help: http://www.physicsclassroom.com/Class/vectors/U3L3e.cfm .

Essentially, you need to calculate the angle of inclination. If the angle is \theta , then the acceleration depends on sin(\theta).

I am assuming z as the vertical dimension.

if dx,dy and dz is are the gradients in each directions, dw = sqrt( dx^2+dy^2). \theta = tan_inverse( dz/dw). Acceleration = g*sin(\theta).

NOTE: You can directly calculate sin(\theta) without explicitly calculating \theta. sin(\theta) = dz/sqrt(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2).

=== More formal description ===

Let x be the east-west dimension, y be the north-south dimension and z be the up-down dimension.

Let z = F(x,y) give the elevation of the terrain at any given location x,y.

Calculate dz/dx = fx(x,y) and dz/dy = fy(x,y), the partial derivatives of z w.r.t to x and y.

Now, sin(\theta) = dz/sqrt(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2) = 1/(sqrt( (dx/dz)^2+ (dy/dz)^2 )= 1/(sqrt( (1/fx(x,y))^2, (1/fy(x,y))^2 ).

This is how you calculate sin(\theta).

Comment: This is ultimately what I was going to do but I cant seem to correctly calculate the angle at a given point and that is the issue. How would the angle of the 3D line be established with a given point?

Comment: By "z as the vertical" you mean "into the screen" then yes but why does it matter about Z as its not affecting the slope of the curve?

Comment: @Chris In my formulation z dimension corresponds to vertical dimension of the terrain, and x& y correspond to horizontal plane. If, in your formulation 'y' is the vertical dimension of the terrain, swap 'dy' and 'dz' accordingly.

Comment: Again this gives strange results. After atan(inverse) and after changing to degrees (rather than radians) dont correspond to the curve. I still dont see why Z (or Y in your formula) plays any part in the incline

Answer (score 2):

1. The value of derivation *is* negative when the slope is "downward". And yes, the derivation is the tangent of the slope angle. Only you should pay attention to the directions. They can change the sign, of course. Only you should take dy/dx, not dy/something else. That is all on 2d curves.
2. You mention Z in the last paragraph. You curve is 3D? Then, of course, the term "derivation" should be put more precisely. Derivation of what to what do you need? The second idea is - please, explain better, what do you want. BTW, maybe after you write down the task correctly, you'll see the solution as obvious.

If it is 3D, let us say, you have your curve as 3 functions of x(t), y(t), z(t). then you need dz/dq, where dq= dt*sqrt((dx/dt)^2+(dy/dt)^2). Obviously, isn't it?
As I said, no maths here. Merely Pythagor's theorem and proportions. (I take z as height)

Addition: it can be rerecounted as tan(a)=dz/(dt*sqrt((dx/dt)^2+(dy/dt)^2)) => tan(a)=(dz/dt)/sqrt((dx/dt)^2+(dy/dt)^2)) ==> a=ATAN((dz/dt)/sqrt((dx/dt)^2+(dy/dt)^2)). But look out for directions you are moving! They can reverse the sign. For under sqrt(^2+^2) we have lost the direction of the dt proection.

Comment: Yes this is a 3D curve, and the other answer is around inclined planes which is what I am trying to do but I was trying to calculate the angles correctly first. Do I ignore the Z axis in this situation?

Comment: In your example is dx, dy, dz the gradient values? and im assuming by dz/dq is to atan can be calculated?

Comment: Atan -yes. As for gradient? Sorry, I am from physics. For me, gradient is a 3d derivation of a scalar function in 3d space. I mean here : you have you curve as 3 functions of x(t), y(t), z(t). so, they have dx/dt... and so on. look answer - addition.